# Odoo 9 Module Creation Documentation Error

Tags: module, odoo

I have been following the module creation tutorial (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html) and it simply doesn't work.

I think it is something to do with the files that the tutorial mentions are inconsistent with the files created by the scaffold command, but I can't work out how to resolve the issues.

I followed the steps, but got an error saying:

```
ParseError: "Invalid model name in the action definition.
None" while parsing /etc/odoo/addons/asn_upload/views/asn_upload.xml:42, near

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_asn_upload">
    <field name="name">AsnFile</field>
    <field name="res_model">asn_upload.asn_file</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Add a ASN file</p>
    </field>
</record>
```

Amend:

I tried it on Odoo v8, and got the same error following the example module on the official tutorial. This is my __init__.py and models.py. Still the same error:

__init__.py:

```
coding: utf-8 -*-

import models
import openacademy
import controllers
import models
```

models.py:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class Course(models.Model):
_name = 'openacademy.course'

name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
description = fields.Text()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: @readikus show your model

Comment: hello can u provide more detail about ur model and view and action?????

Comment: I've added some more details - hope they are useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your case Model name is "asn_upload.asn_file" this is when the .py run in odoo and _name = model name is  _(Underscorr) Replaced by .(dot) in posgresSQL conversion when the store the data, that is main resgin   of ParseError: "Invalid model name in the action definition."

if you run this program so just change your model name without underscore.

I hope you understand...